# Previous Year record from Different table

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have store my student database in a table `student`. When the session is over I move the database to different table `alumni`. And I have form for querying those students where I put session/Year selection. For current session I have no problem querying the database. But for querying previous years student database from alumni in the same form I have no idea how I would query. I just used the following code but this code is limited to one previous year and do not cover the whole past years. Please help me as I am new to this.

```
 $regd=$_GET['regd'];
 $yr=$_GET['Year'];

 $pyr=date("Y")-1;//Current Year minus one equals to Previous year.
 if($yr==$pyr){
 $query_pic = "SELECT * FROM alumni WHERE regd='$regd' and Year='$yr'";
 }else{
  $query_pic = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE regd='$regd' and Year='$yr'";
 }
```

Now I want to dynamically select all the past years student database which were stored in `alumni` table.

Comment: Hint: Look into `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Comment: If you want to select without restricting to a certain year … well then take the year condition out of the WHERE clause …

Comment: Just a tip: Why not have columns `year_started` `graduated_year`  column in `student` table? This way you don't need to have an alumni table. And need to move and update all relations. Seems like a better design.

Comment: take an year drop down check it with current year and execute your if else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $regd=$_GET['regd'];
 $yr=$_GET['Year'];

 $pyr=date("Y")-1;//Current Year minus one equals to Previous year.
 if($yr==$pyr){
 $query_pic = "SELECT * FROM alumni WHERE regd='$regd' and year(Year)<='$yr'";
 }else{
  $query_pic = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE regd='$regd' and Year='$yr'";
 }
```

Comment: So how do I select current year? And how do I select the years before previous years?

Comment: I could not get your point clearly. I think no need to subtract 1 from year.

Comment: As I stored past years student in different table and current students in another table, and still I only have one form for querying. Please explain a bit about your answer.

Comment: here i have used mysql function of year() which is returns only year value from date format

Comment: So can I leave `$pyr=date("Y")-1;` code and if function safely? Thanks for great help. Even though I haven't tested, it looks as though this would be working fine and right.

Comment: If you get your answer, accept this. It may helpful some other else. Thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that submitting the form with the value 2014 for the year input should display all  students in alumni having year less or equal 2014 then try this:

```
$regd=$_GET['regd'];

$yr=$_GET['Year'];

$query_pic = "SELECT * FROM alumni WHERE regd='$regd' and Year<=$yr";
```

instead if you don't want to include current year just remove the = sign

**EDIT**

As you are using the same form for both tables you may continue using the condition :

```
$regd=$_GET['regd'];

$yr=$_GET['Year'];
$pyr=date("Y")-1;//Current Year minus one equals to Previous year.
 if($yr==$pyr){
 $query_pic = "SELECT * FROM alumni WHERE regd='$regd' and Year='$yr'";
 }else{
 $query_pic = "SELECT * FROM alumni WHERE regd='$regd' and Year<=$yr";
 }
```

So now if you select 2014 , the results from students table are returned else the results from alumni having year less or equal the selected..

Comment: current year students are stored in `student` table. Please can you complete your answer. I started to understand.

Comment: You said that you have a form with 2 inputs , you select the year you want the result to stop on , so if you want to see all students before 2012 you select 2012 and submit then you add the code in the submit page , you have the choice to delete the = sign if you want to exclude selected year from the results

Comment: Sorry for my English. Suppose I want to select students from 2013 or before, the code will query alumni table, and for current student, the `student` table will be queried.